# Product page getting a static page title

Tags: magento2

On every page there is static product title "My Dashboard".Although i had enter product name in magento admin but not showing on proudct page.Any guide

[image]

Comment: Definitely this is your wrong customization. Check that.

Comment: Yes that is.I had fix this